# Creating a Search Bar for a Tabular form in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle APEX 4.2, I have created a Tabular form. There is currently over a 1000 rows of data, so I want to create a search bar that sorts through the form and shows me the specific data I want. I have found some suggestions to make a dynamic button that refreshes the page, but that has not work. Is there a way for me to make this search bar?

Comment: I'd say that's a classic example for an Interactive report

Comment: I wanted to use an Interactive report, but i need to add a column where the user was able to choose if they wanted to send an email or not.

Comment: Yah, I was suggested that a tabular form would be the way to go.

Comment: Maybe you should detail a little more what you have tried so far. Why the refresh button didn't do it, or how you defined it.

Comment: Just found the solution to my issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed by issue, I set my button to "submit" instead of "dynamic action" and the text box's "source used" setting to "Only when current value in session state is null". I then set the link that brings the user to the tabular form page to clear the cache for it; this allowed the search to refresh when the user decides to go to the page again.